# To run Aerogear UPS on Tomcat vs Find another open source solution (running on Tomcat)

Tags: tomcat, push-notification, aerogear

I'm evaluating Aerogear UPS to send push notifications to my users using iOS/Android/Windows Apps. Featurewise, Aerogear UPS covers all my requirements, except it is a JBoss project, and cannot be deployed and run on Tomcat server (out of the box). But unforatunately, our host environment would only allow Tomcat instead of Jboss.

Anybody who has experience to make Aerogear UPS running on Tomcat? Or it is a better idea to choose a different solution?

Comment: I believe this kind of question is off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: yes, I realized that. So I edited my question... hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

UPS does not support Tomcat.

However if you want to give it a shot then at a minimum you will need to add to Tomcat jars for Jax-RS and CDI and define two JNDI database resources, jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS and jboss/datasources/UnifiedPushDS.  Even then you may still run into missing dependencies and jboss specific APIs (I haven't done a code review to test any of these assumptions).

However, if you get it running please let us know on aerogear-dev and aerogear-users.  It will be really exciting.